# export SWT app as jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt, windowbuilder

I installed WindowBuilder to Eclipse and created program that consist of one class. This class is generated directly by WinowsBuilder and only contains one empty window. I can run this program on eclipse. I exported program to jar file, but it throws error when i try to launch it. Error says that "The Java JAR "gui.jar" could not be launched."
Tried to follow this tutorial http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program%3F but it still not working.

update: when launching jar file via terminal i got following error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: swing2swt/layout/BorderLayout
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: swing2swt.layout.BorderLayout
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
```

How should I export SWT application as stand alone jar?

Comment: If you run the jar from the command line (e.g. `java -jar MyJar.jar`), what error do you get?

Comment: Well. apparently one of your libraries (swing2swt) isn't exported with the jar. Is it on your classpath and did you tell Eclipse to export it as well?

Comment: nope. in tutorial this was not mentioned, so i missed it.
But I did it already. the got error that says "Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions". After some googling i managed to open program with command "java -XstartOnFirstThread -jar gui.jar". Here fallows another question - how to make it run without any terminals and additional arguments? can you give my a link for a start?

Comment: You could create a proper application for OSX. [Here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/) is a tutorial.

Comment: [Here](http://mchr3k.github.io/swtjar/osxapp.html) is another one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you want to make your posts as an answer, i will definitely mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as a conclusion from the comments above:

- You'll need to include all the libraries you reference in the jar export process, otherwise they won't be included in the jar file.
- Since you're running OSX, you'll either need to use the VM argument `-XstartOnFirstThread` when starting your jar, or you can create a proper OSX application as described [here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/macosx/) and [here](http://mchr3k.github.io/swtjar/osxapp.html)